# How to create shadow efffect on vertical line

Tags: html, css, shadow

I'm trying to determine if there is a css method for creating shadow vertical lines as in this example

[image]

Comment: Take a look at `box-shadow`

    http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/

Comment: Yeah you can do this with css using box-shadow. Use 2 div's or pseudo element.

Comment: The most common way of doing that is giving the right border of one element (like a floated li) a light color and the left border of the next element a dark border.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VKpNQ/)

Just use the `box-shadow` and play with it to get the best result for you.

```
.line {
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 2px 0px 2px #888;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use box shadows for this

```
box-shadow: 1px 0px 0 blue, 2px 0px 0 red;
```

this will create 2 lines on the right side of the element one will be red the other one blue

But keep in mind that this is not supported in IE8 and lower so I would recommend using css borders for one of the lines.

Using a border and a box shadow:

```
box-shadow: 1px 0px 0 red; border-right: 1px solid blue;
```

More info on box shadows:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp